# Change data before Enter Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a problem, suppose the list receives data from the database, now for example, I want to add a character to each txt2 property, so if our data was "Test", what it displays is "Test2" In fact, the data must be clearly changed before it enters the box list What is the best way to have high speed and performance?

// in xml

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" >
<ListBox.item>
<TextBlock Text="{binding txt1}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{binding txt2}"/>
</ListBox.item>
 </ListBox>
```

// in code behind

```
List<File> list;
list = db.Files.toList();

lb.ItemSource=list;
```

//class File

```
public class File{
public string txt1;
public string txt2;
}
```

Comment: Your `File` class is all kinds of broken. `Public` should be `public` and both of the members aren't visible outside of the class since the default modifier for class members is `private`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to add "2" to your `txt1`, you have to change `txt2` in class file:

```cs
public string txt2 { get { return txt1 + "2";} }
```

So, it'll work as you created class file with `txt1` and the property `txt2` accept the value of `txt1` and add your custom value of "2".

If you want to increment the last number `txt1` could have by 1, you have to substring it and increase it by one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is an example, I wanted to see what is the best way to do this when there is a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify each `txt2` property in the presentation layer, you need to iterate through all objects that you received from the data access layer and set all these properties.

There are no magic tricks here. Depending on the number of items, you could possible speed things up a bit by iterating in parallel:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list, item => item.txt2 = "some new value...");
```

You will need to iterate through all items, one way or another, unless you apply UI virtualization and modify the `Text` property of the actual `TextBlock` elements that gets loaded and reused on demand. I wouldn't recommend this approach though.